# SQL help is needed in merging two tables

Tags: sql, merge

I have a [Date] Column in [Table1] and a column [Actions] in [Table2]

[Table1] looks like:

```
Date
----
2018-01-01
2018-01-02
...
2018-02-28
2018-03-01
...
2018-12-31
```

[Table2] looks like:

```
Actions
-------
Action1
Action2
Action3
...
```

I want to create a [Table3] to look like this:

```
Date       | Actions 
--------------------
2018-01-01 | Action1
2018-01-02 | Action1
...
2018-02-28 | Action1
2018-03-01 | Action1
...
2018-12-31 | Action1
2018-01-01 | Action2
2018-01-02 | Action2
...
2018-02-28 | Action2
2018-03-01 | Action2
...
2018-12-31 | Action2
2018-01-01 | Action3
2018-01-02 | Action3
...
2018-02-28 | Action3
2018-03-01 | Action3
...
2018-12-31 | Action3
...
```

In other words to assign in all dates all actions. Is there an SQL command to do that? Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tab1,tab2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want a Cartesian product.  In SQL, you do this using `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select t1.date, t2.action
from t1 cross join
     t2
order by t2.action, t1.date;
```

How you save this into a table depends on the database you are using.  Typically it would either be `create table table3 as select . . .` or `select . . . into table3 from . . .`.

Answer (score 0):

below query also will give Cartesian product output

```
SELECT * FROM table1,table2
```